# 010 Editor template: Parsing 7-bit encoded int for length-prefixed string

Tags: c, string, data-structures

In a *010 Editor* template (C/C++ like syntax) I want to parse a string that was written with Microsoft .Net's `BinaryWriter` class like so:

```
myBinaryWriter.Write("hello");
```

This writes out a length-prefixed string, where the length is encoded with `Write7BitEncodedInt`. Here is the .Net source for writing the length, for reference:

```
// Write out an int 7 bits at a time.  The high bit of the byte, 
// when on, tells reader to continue reading more bytes. 
uint v = (uint) value;   // support negative numbers
while (v >= 0x80) { 
    Write((byte) (v | 0x80));
    v >>= 7;
}
Write((byte)v);
```

How would a struct definition in a 010 Editor template syntax look like to parse a string encoded like that?

Comment: Does your problem lie in understanding the encoding or formulating a decoder in the particular scripting language? In C you would do something along the lines of `unsigned c, v = 0, b = 0; do v |= (c = Read()) & 0x7F) << b; while(b += 7, c & 0x80);`. Whether or how that translates to a parser script for you HEX editor I do not know, but given the C tag I suppose it might be a starting point.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I think I understand the encoding, but neither am I familar with C nor with bit manipulation and pointer operations. I think I could transfer a pure C solution into the editor's scripting language if it doesn't use too many unsupported features. Pointers for example are not supported, but a null-terminated "string" type exists instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rough way of handling parsing .net binary strings as an 010 Editor Binary Template, it handles 1 and 2 byte length prefixes, but it should be straightforward to expand it to longer strings with a loop. I had previously been parsing strings with a byte hardcoded as string length but as soon as I had a string that was 128 in length that failed, but this seems to work:

```
typedef struct
{    
    ubyte stringLength;
    local int stringLengthLocal = stringLength;
    if(stringLength > 127)
    {
        stringLengthLocal = (ubyte)stringLength & (ubyte)127;
        ubyte stringLength2;
        stringLengthLocal += stringLength2 * 128;
    }

    char stringValue[stringLengthLocal] <optimize=false>;
} String;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a function that does two things: (1) extract the content length; (2) give you a pointer to where the "real" content starts.
See the following code, which should fulfill these two requirements:

```
int getLength(const unsigned char *str, int *content_offset)
{
    int result = 0, moreBytes=0, pos=0;
    do
    {
        unsigned char value7Bit = str[pos];
        result = (result << 7) | (value7Bit & 0x7F);
        moreBytes = value7Bit & 0x80;
        pos++;
    }
    while (moreBytes);

    if(content_offset)
        *content_offset = pos;

    return result;
}


int main() {

    unsigned char str[] = "\x81\x01teststring, which should contain 129 characters.....";

    int content_offset=0;
    int length = getLength(str, &content_offset);

    printf("length: %d; content: '%s'\n", length, str+content_offset);
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: The encoder in the sample code looks to be little-endian though, and despite the tag I gather that it is to be implemented in a scripting language with a C-like syntax.